# Delete repetitive words text file

Tags: ruby

I'm pretty sure I got it wrong. But something like this perhaps?

```
file_names = ['phone_numbers.txt']
file_names.each do |file_name|
  words_to_exclude = ["Employee Marked Urgency as: low", "Employee Marked Urgency as: high"]
  text = File.read(file_name)
  lines = text.split("\n")
  new_contents = lines.uniq.reject do |word|
    words_to_exclude.include? word
  end.join("\n")
  File.open(file_name, "w") { |file| file.puts new_contents }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split it up by newline, call `uniq` on that list, and then join with newlines before writing.

```
file_names = ['phone_numbers.txt']
file_names.each do |file_name|
  text = File.read(file_name)
  lines = text.split("\n")
  new_contents = lines.uniq.join("\n")
  File.open(file_name, "w") { |file| file.puts new_contents }
end
```

Note that you should not use `|file_names|` because it is not accurate. That variable refers to a *single* filename (the current one in the loop). So I changed it to `file_name`.

To follow to your question, if you want to filter out words from the using using some metric other than uniqueness, you can use [Enumerable#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) or [Enumerable#reject](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-select). For example:

```
words_to_exclude = ["foo", "bar"]
new_contents = lines.uniq.reject do |word|
  words_to_exclude.include? word
end.join("\n")
```

Comment: What about if I want to exclude some repetitive phrases. How would that look like?

Comment: Let me test it out. Give me a min

Comment: @Yeager yeah, it looks good to me ... but does it work for you? That's what's important

Comment: unfortunately not. It doesn't change the file at all

Comment: can you paste the content of the text file?

Comment: Its a lot. 
Employee Name: Cody.
Email: cody.@target.com
Employee Marked Urgency as: low
Employee Name: Cody.
Email: cody@target.com
Employee Marked Urgency as: high
Phone number: 71556323743
Employee Marked Urgency as: high

Comment: this is a portion of it buts its repetitive

Comment: OK ... can you paste it in the question and format it as code? All the formatting is lost when you paste into a comment, and it's important because the code is saying "if _the entire line contents_ equals this"